# c# azure function trigger: create a csv file from a given string

Tags: c#, azure-functions

i am trying to create a csv file from a string. I was able to create the csv file as string like so:

```
private void SaveToCsv<T>(List<T> reportData)

    {
        var lines = new List<string>();
        IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).OfType<PropertyDescriptor>();
        var header = string.Join(",", props.ToList().Select(x => x.Name));
        lines.Add(header);
        var valueLines = reportData.Select(row => string.Join(",", header.Split(',').Select(a => row.GetType().GetProperty(a).GetValue(row, null))));
        lines.AddRange(valueLines);

    }
```

But I cannot seem to find out how to create an actual .csv file from the string in `lines`, as the function app cannot follow a specific path (eg: D://drive/user/xya)

How do I create a file in code without a path in a function app?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the CSV file to an Azure File/Blob Storage or something similar?

Comment: I red about this, but I wasnt sure if I needed that. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Azure Functions are considered "serverless", so they are just pieces of code that runs on a "somewhat random" environment. You should take your storage concerns elsewhere like Blob Storage or File Storage. Your Azure Function is just a method that'll run in some machine, where you don't really care about its filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if the below steps helps to work around:**

- After generating the CSV Files, to store them you need the storage account. It is automatically created when creating the Azure Function App.
- Update the Storage account name, connection string and file path in `local.settings.json` as well as in the configuration of the Azure Function App in the portal.
- Here `File_path` is the blob container folder path where you're going to save the CSV files.
- Add the CORS option through portal or code to run out of the issues like allowing the requests from your local IP addresses, current IP address if connected to VPN.
- Refer this [article](http://www.mattruma.com/adventures-with-azure-storage-read-write-files-to-blob-storage-from-azure-functions/) for practical workaround and the code.
- If you want to save the CSV files in the temporary location of the Azure Functions, then refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712009/save-file-to-temporary-location-in-azure-functions)

**References:**

1. [Storage Consideration of Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations)
2. To mount Azure local storage as a local file, refer to this [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/661911/how-can-i-access-a-34local34-path-in-an-azure-func.html)
3. [Accessing Azure File Storage from Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109286/accessing-azure-file-storage-from-azure-function)