# How can I publish (from VS 2022), read from and write to the equivalent of an "app data" directory within my Azure Functions function code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I need to include files in my Azure functions deployment (from Visual Studio). I need to be able to access the equivalent of an "app data" directory from my Azure function - both to read uploaded files and to write temporary files I need to invoke my function code. There've been many (old) questions relating to this topic, but the responses usually cite using the ExecutionContext object (which now appears to be obsolete). And the FunctionContext parameter doesn't seem to help.

If need be, I can use blob storage input bindings to pass in the input file(s), but I will still need to have a temp directory to execute my code.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

To include files in Azure function deployment you need to add `<ItemGroup>` in `.csproj` file.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
 <None Include="utility\**\*"> # utility\**\* is used add all the subdirectories and files inside utility folder
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**To Read existing file :**

In `In-process` you can use `ExecutionContext` to use `FunctionAppDirectory` to get existing file path. For reference check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767946/how-to-use-local-files-in-an-azure-function-hosted-on-the-linux-consumption-plan/77779377#77779377).

In `Isolated` use this(which works both in Linux and Windows):

```cs
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

**To Create Temporary files and write in it :**
Thanks to @silent. For reference check [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712009/save-file-to-temporary-location-in-azure-functions)

```cs
string newpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "newfile.txt");
```

**#My Directory :**
[image]

**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            
            string readFile = File.ReadAllText(path + "/utility/hello.txt");

            string newpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "newfile.txt");

            File.WriteAllText(newpath, "hello from new tempfile 'newfile.txt'");

            string newFilecontent= File.ReadAllText(newpath);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString($"Welcome to Azure Functions!\n\n{readFile.ToString()}\n\nNew file content; {newFilecontent}");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.38.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="utility\**\*">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

## `OUTPUT`:

```
Welcome to Azure Functions!

Hello from hello.txt from  utility folder

New file content; hello from new tempfile 'newfile.txt'
```

[image]